# Redirect Urls With Parameters Using Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I did a "site:" command in google to view the indexed urls and found a lot of urls with parameters all pointing to the same page.

Its a static site, but about 5 years ago it was a Wordpress site, which may be how those links were created and indexed by Google.  The 3 main links I found are as follows.  They all look like these 3 but with different id's.

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_banners&task=click&bid=41

http://example.com/?option=com_content&view=article&id=86&Itemid=201

http://example.com/phlebotomy-jobs?&pid=6774238282444518&q=Phlebotomy&pg=7

My question is how do I redirect these links, with all of the different parameter ids, to their corresponding pages.  The first two go to the homepage and the 3rd one goes to a /phlebotomy-jobs page.

So, what I'm looking for is, for example, this url: http://example.com/phlebotomy-jobs?&pid=6774238282444518&q=Phlebotomy&pg=7 to redirect to http://example.com/phlebotomy-jobs

Basically removing everything from the ? on.

Comment: Do you use any sort of framework?

Comment: No, I dont use a framework.  Built from scratch. 90% html with a little php and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php?$ /path/page.php [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ /path/page.php [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phlebotomy-jobs?$ /path/page.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` RewriteRule Flag appends the query string.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

**Edit:**

Since you're not concerned with retaining the query strings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/index.php$|^/$|^/phlebotomy-jobs$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Note: This method prevents passing **any** query strings to either of those two pages.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to remove everything from the ? on. It just adds to the url right before the question mark. Perhaps I didnt implement it right or wasn't completely clear.  For example, this url: http://example.com/phlebotomy-jobs?&pid=6774238282444518&q=Phlebotomy&pg=7 should redirect to http://example.com/phlebotomy-jobs

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if it's the "best" way, but this, for example, works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```